# Parameter getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

First question here... so hi guys!
So, I was doing a function where I should get the higher and lower numbers from an array and I came with this code:

```
const arraySort = (numbers) =>{
    if (!numbers) return console.log('No numbers');
    if (Array.isArray(numbers) === false) return console.log('No array!');
    if (numbers.includes(undefined)) return console.log('undefined in the array');
    let newnumbers=numbers.sort();
    
    let newArray = [newnumbers.reverse().pop(),newnumbers.pop()];
    console.log(`The higher and lower number from the array [${numbers}] is [${newArray}]`);
}
```

And what I get is 'The higher and lower number from the array [4] is [-5,3]'. Why my *numbers* parameter is overwritten? I tried to create the *newnumbers* variable for using the .pop() and .sort() methods but still, the original variable is getting overwritten and I don't really know why. Can someone throw me some light on it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sort()` modifies the array in place. Make a copy of the array before sorting it.

Comment: `newnumbers` is not a copy of the array. It's a second variable pointing at the same array as `numbers`. You can use `numbers.slice()` to make a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of your code is modifying the original array:

`sort(), reverse(), pop()` all affect the original array.

You should start with making a copy.

```js
const arraySort = (numbers) =>{
    if (!numbers) return console.log('No numbers');
    if (Array.isArray(numbers) === false) return console.log('No array!');
    if (numbers.includes(undefined)) return console.log('undefined in the array');
    let newnumbers=[...numbers];
    newnumbers.sort();
    
    let newArray = [newnumbers[newnumbers.length-1],newnumbers[0]];
    console.log(`The higher and lower number from the array [${numbers}] is [${newArray}]`);
}

arraySort([1,2,6,3,5,4]);
```

`pop()` removes the array elements, so you are better off working with indices when returning max and min elements.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse()` and `sort()` modifies the original array. So here I'm taking the 1st and Last index of the sorted array.

```js
const arraySort = (numbers) => {
  if (!numbers) return console.log('No numbers');
  if (Array.isArray(numbers) === false) return console.log('No array!');
  if (numbers.includes(undefined)) return console.log('undefined in the array');
  numbers.sort();

  let newArray = [numbers[0], numbers[numbers.length -1]];
  console.log(`The higher and lower number from the array [${numbers}] is [${newArray}]`);
}

arraySort([4,5,1,2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

sort and reverse modify the original array. Instead look to create a deepcopy if you dont want to mutate them using the spread operator. I have updated the function below:

```
var arraySort = (numbers) =>{
    if (!numbers) return console.log('No numbers');
    if (Array.isArray(numbers) === false) return console.log('No array!');
    if (numbers.includes(undefined)) return console.log('undefined in the array');
    let newnumbers = [...numbers]
    newnumbers.sort();
    console.log(newnumbers)
    let newArray = [newnumbers[newnumbers.length - 1],newnumbers[0]];
    console.log(`The higher and lower number from the array [${numbers}] is [${newArray}]`);
    }
```